# HTML2PDF has blurry pdf output

Tags: php, html2pdf

I need some help, why is it that the resolution of my `html2pdf` is blurry? How can I adjust the resolution?.

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: @VinodKumar php sir.

Comment: Oh OK. Please call me Vinod. I believe you are losing quality only on images and not text (since they are vector based already), refer this link http://www.html2pdf.solutions/en/Support/Parameters_for_html2pdf.htm You have an option to set the quality of the image. Let me know if it helps

Comment: @VinodKumar sir Vinod, my problem is the text sir, the pdf has no image .

Comment: can you show the code ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some parameters like `ImageQuality` and `DisablePdfCompression` you have to pass which is defining the image quality, pdf compression and pdf size. Here is some details of it.

**ImageQuality**

Integer: Values from 1 to 100 resp. 101. Default is 101 (lossless compression)
Can be used to decrease PDF files size. The smaller the value the smaller the PDF file size. A reasonable value is 75.

**DisablePdfCompression**

Integer: 0 (Standard), 1 do not use lossless compression on pdf objects

For more details : http://www.html2pdf.solutions/en/Support/Parameters_for_html2pdf.htm

Answer (score 11):

It's work for me!

```
var opt = {
      margin: [15, 0, 15, 0],
      filename: `CV-${name}.pdf`,
      image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 1 },
      html2canvas: {
        dpi: 192,
        scale:4,
        letterRendering: true,
        useCORS: true
      },
      jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' }
    };
```

Answer (score 10):

This is an example in js if someone use this lib

https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf#image-type-and-quality

You can pass an option `html2pdf(content, option)`

Try this, `html2pdf(document.body, {html2canvas:  { scale: 4 }})`

I guess in php, it should be similar.